# Distance and Angle between two points

Tags: c#

Wrong output of angle only getting 45 and not the -135.000 as told?

I have been told to use the following inputs 1X=2,1Y=2, 2X=1, 2Y=1,
to calculate the distance - which outputs the number 1.414 (to 3
digits). Moreover, I have also been told to calculate the angle using
Atan2 and convert radians to degrees - which outputs 45. But... I
have been told the output of the angle should be -135.000 degrees?

I know I'm missing something somewhere?

All sorted! a really big thank-you to The Oddler :)

```
//calculate delta x and delta y between the two points
deltaX = Math.Pow((2X - 1X), 2); 
deltaY = Math.Pow((2Y - 1Y), 2);

//pythagras theorem for distance
distance = Math.Sqrt(deltaY + deltaX);

//atan2 for angle
radians = Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

//radians into degrees
angle = radians * (180 / Math.PI);

Output: distance = 1.414
        angle = 45
```

Comment: I think you have a typo (probably here) since you declared deltax twice

Comment: You also have this variable mentioned delatY which is another typo, which would presumably stop this from compiling..

Answer (score 3):

In c# variables can't start with a number, so `1X` isn't a valid variable name. Change it to `X1` and it should be fine. Also make sure you don't use the squared delta for the angle.

```
float X1=2, Y1=2, X2=1, Y2=1; //Don't start variable names with number

//calculate delta x and delta y between the two points
var deltaX = Math.Pow((X2 - X1), 2); 
var deltaY = Math.Pow((Y2 - Y1), 2);

//pythagras theorem for distance
var distance = Math.Sqrt(deltaY + deltaX);

//atan2 for angle
var radians = Math.Atan2((Y2 - Y1), (X2 - X1)); // Don't use squared delta

//radians into degrees
var angle = radians * (180 / Math.PI);

Console.WriteLine("Dist = " + distance);
Console.WriteLine("Angle = " + angle);
```

And a little fiddle to show it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fzyVFW

Comment: Thank-you... I knew I messed up somewhere :)

Comment: Np, glad it helped. If this answer solved your problem you should accept this, this way other people who might find it know what helped you ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that deltaX and deltaY are squared in your code. So

```
radians = Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
```

returns the wrong number.

I haven't tested it, but

```
//calculate delta x and delta y between the two points

deltaX = X2 - X1;
deltaY = Y2 - Y1;

//pythagoras theorem for distance
distance = Math.Sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY);

//atan2 for angle
radians = Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

//radians into degrees
angle = radians * (180 / Math.PI);
```

should work.

Comment: The angle is still showing 45?