# MS Chart connecting all datapoints without lines crossing

Tags: c#, charts

I have datapoints in a MS chart and I would like to connect all these datapoints with lines, where none of the lines cross each other. Each datapoint will be connected to 2 other datapoints.

The plot should look like a closed loop, it is very important that there will be no lines that cross on top of another.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know what part is not clear for you, please do tell me. If the plot has 3 points, it should become a triangle. If it has 4 points, should become a tetragon. 5 points should become a pentagon.. and so on. Each point will be connected only to 2 other points. None of the connecting lines must cross.

Edit: This connection must be done no matter which order the data points are entered

Edit 2: I have edited the previous question today, thats why the wording is similar. Then I saw it was closed so I opened this one.

Comment: sure, examples with 3 or 4 points may look simple but what about 10 or 100? Also: The __order is always what determines the connections__. That is how line chart works. But again: It is only doable with YOUR knowledge about those points! Will they really always be concave? What about a 10x10 grid or points? Obvious? Surely not..

Comment: Never said that it was easy to implement, otherwise I wouldn't be asking. You don't need to be so rude against a new programmer trying to find answers.

Comment: Not meaning to be rude, my friend. But in fact you did ask about an 'easy way'. I'll post a not so easy way if you want me to..

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you would be willing to spend time on helping me with that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I misspoke: It actually is not that hard, that is unless one wants more restrictions than what you gave. Here is a **radar-beam** method that ought to work:

- Let's start with a list of points
- From it we create a  `List<Tuple<PointF, float, float>>`
- Then we find the minimum and maximum x and y values and from these the center point `c`
- Next we fill each Tuple's two floats by calculating the angle and the distance between each point and the center `c`
- Finally we order by angle and then by distance
- Now we can traverse the list and create `DataPoints` from it we add to our `Series`.
- To close the loop we add the first `DataPoint` again at the end.

This connects without any crossings but I believe some results will look uglier than what a hand-crafted solution would be. In fact most examples will look like an explosion ;-)

OTOH: Isn't is remarkable how those lines add a visible structure to the chaos?

Here is an example with 100 random points.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try to implement it in the way you have described!
Can you also share the code you have used for this example?

Comment: Well, most of the tasks are actually one-liner using linq, e.g. `float mix = points.Min(x => x.X);`. It'll be more instructive to give it a try yourself; I'll help out if you run into problems tomorrow. Expand the question if necessary. I used [this link for the math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358036/distance-and-angle-between-two-points). The whole demo program is 100 lines including white spacem using clauses and setting up a few chart properties..

Comment: Thanks once again, I'll try now and let you know!

Comment: Really cool +1. Posting only an explanation and not the code itself was a gangster move though...:O)

Comment: Works like a charm! I have implemented into my code, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :)