# How to find inner border of shape represented as point collection?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, geometry

I need to get inner border of shape. Previously, I found nearest point to the center of shape in case of square or circle shape, but how can I do it in M-shape case.

What I have (I need marked points at screenshot №2):

---

[image: Canvas]

---

[image]

---

Any algorithms, steps to find these points?

UPD: Now, I have segments direction vector like (1, 0) or (0.5, 0.5)

Comment: Any thoughts from yourself? How would you differentiate between the "inside" and the "outside"? Seems rather arbitrary in this example case.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I think they mean for the algorithm to create a shape that does not contain any of the black dots inside.

Comment: So your question is which of the three points in each small group is "inner" or closest to center?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I have some cases with square and circle, I just found center and get nearest points. But in this M or П-shape cases center bad idea.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks Yeah, but in this case center location is outside of the shape

Comment: @MaxDoesStuff an "M" shape consisting of lines joining dots is not closed so cannot *contain* dots - therefore the concept of "inside" is not well-defined without any further constraints.

Comment: But how do you define the connections between points? Smallest shape circumference? Random? Maybe you can just take closest points to each other?

Comment: @WorldTV Could you provide an example of how an M shape would be solved by your algorithm? It would help with insight for a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure this problem is well-defined. You may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909054/ms-chart-connecting-all-datapoints-without-lines-crossing/45909376?r=SearchResults&s=2|41.4072#45909376) for an idea, not necessarily for the solution you have in mind, though...

Comment: @TaW Yeah I saw that, but the problem is that center is outside of shape

Comment: Do you think there is only one solutionfor he resulting shape?

Comment: How do you decide which edges to draw? Why not like [this](https://ibb.co/mDk3WkP), [this](https://ibb.co/C1mpgWD) or [this](https://ibb.co/W6YphXr)?

Comment: @trincot Updated question, now I receive direction of this segment, but still don't know how to selected inner point

Comment: To be clear, it's room and points represent corners.

Comment: Could you be more specific still? Do I understand correctly that you have as input: (1) the x,y coordinates of *n* points of which some are clustered together (always clusters of 3??) (2) the dx, dy coordinates of *m* vectors, where *m* is also the number of points to select from the *n* points. Are these vectors *exact*, so that once you select the starting point, they can only end in one other point? If so, then what really is the question? Or are the coordinates not exact, and is there a margin? Which is the margin? This question needs a more detailed played out example.

Comment: @trincot Input: 
(1) From 2 to 4 points(start of the wall)
(2) From 2 to 4 points(ends of the wall)
(3) Direction represented as vector from start point #1. Current I use Math.Atan2(y,x) to convert it to angle

Vector exact, but if you look at the image they can be reversed(not in clockwise direction for example)

Comment: There remains a lot unanswered. I move on.

Comment: Take a look at the [Ball Pivoting](https://lidarwidgets.com/samples/bpa_tvcg.pdf) algorithm. It's an algo for triangulation, but once you have it you can get the hull. Or modify slighly the algo to get the hull directly. The tricky part is choosing the right diameter of the ball.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first step is to simplify by averaging near-neighbour dots into a single point. Then find the smallest convex polygon that contains all points (easily done). Then selectively punch some sides in to meet the internal points (the polygon becomes concave). There are many ways to select which sides to punch in, and which points to punch in to first, and I can't be sure what's best without knowing more about your specific goals.

A simple approach would be to deal first with those points that are closest to an existing side, and punch the nearest side in to meet them. But you may want to apply other scoring conditions to choose the best points to deal with first and the best sides to punch in. For instance, you may want to give higher scores to points that are closely vertically or horizontally aligned with one of the vertices of the current polygon, so that they are dealt with earlier rather than later; and give the sides adjoining that vertex a higher score as candidates for punching in. You probably also want to award longer sides with higher scores as candidates for punching in.

I imagine that with a few simple weighting criteria such as these, you will quickly get some sensible results.

Finally, if you wish, you can refer back to your original set of unaveraged dots, and make further small adjustments to the shape to ensure that all those dots fall outside its boundaries.